# Parse data in background Swift

Tags: ios, background, parse-platform, push, fetch

I'm extremely new to swift and I need some help. I'm tying to update Parse in the AppDelegate with Daily Background Fetch. The weird thing is this works on the simulator but does not work on my actual device. When I open the app again though the notifications fire. Any help would be appreciated.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Do something
    var rankCout = 1
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Person")
    query.orderByDescending("Score")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
        if error == nil
        {


            for object in objects
            {

                if ((object["Name"]) as NSString ==  (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("USERNAME")) as NSString)
                {

                    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
                    notification.alertBody = "TEST"

                    println("PUSH")
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked permissions on your device to receive notifications and to run in the background?

Comment: Did you `registerUserNotificationSettings` as outlined in [Registering, Scheduling, and Handling User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW25) section of the _Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide_?

Comment: Yeah I have this: `let myType:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge`                                  
`let mySettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: myType, categories: nil)`
`IApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)` `IApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)`